# How to separate row entries in a csv file into distinct columns with duplicate labels in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I need to restructure a .csv file that follows this structure:

```
a b
1 2
3 4
5 6
...
```

Into this new structure:

```
a b a b a b ...
1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
```

I don't know how to do this efficiently without iterating over each row. Is there a more efficient way of doing this in Python?

Comment: You have to read the input at least once, so there's not way around reading the entire input, i.e., "iterate over each row". If you're looking for a solution without for loops, that's certainly possible: `' '.join([line.strip() for line in f.readlines()])` where `f` is the file you `open`ed. Not sure if you also have `a` and `b` in the file and want it in the output. If you do, you will have to do add some extra code for that, but it'll follow a similar pattern.

Comment: I edited the tags since the question doesn't involve JSON, arrays, or dataframes. If you're thinking about those as *possible solutions*, you might want to [edit] and mention them. Though personally I don't see JSON being helpful.

Comment: What's wrong with iterating over each row? How else do you want to get at the data of each row?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. This is a good first question! The only thing I would say is, iterating over each row doesn't sound inefficient to me, though it might be more legwork than using something like Pandas. It'd help to add what you've tried so we can build on it or correct any mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the .csv to a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')

# create a new df
new_df = pd.DataFrame([df.to_numpy().ravel()], columns=df.columns.to_list() * len(df))
print(new_df)
```

Prints:

```
   a  b  a  b  a  b
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

---

To save the new dataframe:

```py
new_df.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution in pure Python (without bringing out the big guns such as Pandas ...):

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    columns = f.readline().strip().split()
    rows = f.read().strip().split("\n")
    print(' '.join(len(rows) * columns))
    print(' '.join(r.strip() for r in rows))
```

Answer (score 0):

If file is in csv format i.e.

```
a,b
1,2
3,4
....
```

below approach can be used

```
import csv

# Input and output file names
input_file = 'input.csv'
output_file = 'output.csv'

# Reading CSV file
with open(input_file, 'r') as input_file_csv:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file_csv)
    rows = list(reader)
    # [['a', 'b'], ['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]

row1 = [item for i in range(len(rows)-1) for item in rows[0]]
# ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']

row2 = [item for i in range(1,len(rows)) for item in rows[i]]
# ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

# Write to CSV file
with open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as output_file_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file_csv)
    writer.writerow(row1)
    writer.writerow(row2)
```

Comment: Cleaner: `row1 = rows[0] * (len(rows)-1)` and `row2 = [item for row in rows[1:] for item in row]`. Generally in Python, if you're doing `for i in range(len(...))`, there's a better way.

Comment: Or it'd be even cleaner if you followed [ahans's solution](/a/77168680/4518341) and treated the column header separately: `header = next(reader); rows = list(reader)` then `row1 = header * len(rows); row2 = [item for row in rows for item in row]`

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas, we can think of this as pivoting the implied index, which we would normally do with [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), but in this case, it's actually easier to pivot the columns, i.e. [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html).

```
import pandas as pd

delimiter = ' '

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=delimiter)

# Unstack all rows to one row.
# Actually stacks columns, drops the original index, then turns back into a df.
result = df.stack().droplevel(0).to_frame().T
```

Result:

```
   a  b  a  b  a  b
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

Back to CSV:

```
result.to_csv(new_filename, index=False, sep=delimiter)
```

```
a b a b a b
1 2 3 4 5 6
```